# Selenium Java base class for all browser drivers and code which is redundant

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am new in Selenium and Java and I need help with base class. I have I base where I set methods for driver browsers and for its close. Problem is that when I call these method from main always web driver is called and browser is open many times. What is best practice if I don't want to have code duplication
and I want a good structure of project.

Main:

```
public class Main extends TestBase {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        LoginTest LoginTest = new LoginTest();
        LogofTest LogofTest = new LogofTest();
        TestBase TestBase = new TestBase();
        LoginTest.setUpBeforeTestMethod();
        LoginTest.loginAsAdmin();
        LogofTest.logofAsAdmin();
        LoginTest.tearDownAfterTestClass();
    }
}
```

TestBase:

```
public class TestBase {
String a = System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
        "path");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

protected WebDriver setUpBeforeTestClass() {

    return driver;
}

protected void setUpBeforeTestMethod() {
    driver.get("website");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

protected void tearDownAfterTestClass() {
    driver.close();
}}
```

LoginTest:

```
public class LoginTest extends TestBase {

    public void login() throws InterruptedException {
        WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.name("username"));
        username.sendKeys("username");
}
}
```

The main focus is that I don't want to write again

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("website"); System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome,"path");
```

for each test in function or class. So I want to create base class and inherit from it.

Comment: Since these are tests, instead of running it like a program with a `Main` method, you should look into a unit test framework like `junit` or any others that look good to you. Those frameworks have built in concepts of setup and teardown stuff for you to make it easier to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Example `Selenium` Test with `JUnit` using the **Page Object Model**

**TestBase**

```
public class TestBase
{
    private String a = System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path");
    protected WebDriver driver;

    @Before //Before each test case, use BeforeClass for before each test class
    public static void setUpBeforeTestCase() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("website");
    }

    @After
    public static void tearDownAfterTestCase() {
        driver.Quit(); //driver.Close() closes the window, but doesn't properly dispose of the driver
    }
}
```

**LoginTest**:

```
public class LoginTest extends TestBase {

    @Test
    public void loginAndOutAsAdmin(){
        LoginPage loginPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
        LandingPage landingPage =  loginPage.login("adminUser", "adminPassword");
        landingPage.logout();
        //Do some sort of assert here that you are logged out
    }
}
```

**BasePage**

```
public class BasePage
{
    protected WebDriver driver;

    //Other common stuff your Page Objects will do, like wait for an element
}
```

**LoginPage**

```
public class LoginPage extends BasePage
{
    @FindBy(how = How.NAME, using = "username")
    private WebElement usernameBox;

    //something for passwordBox and loginButton

    public LoginPage(WebDriver currentDriver)
    {
        driver = currentDriver;
    }

    public LandingPage login(String username, String password)
    {
        usernameBox.sendKeys(username);
        passwordBox.sendKeys(password);
        loginButton.click();

        return PageFactory.initElements(driver, LandingPage.class);
    }
}
```

I haven't tried to compile this, but that's the basic idea. I'll let you fill in the details.